# How to echo text then abort in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Ruby and want to echo some texts in a controller then abort.

In PHP, I would do

```
echo "something"; exit;
```

How do I do it in RoR?

I've tried

```
render :text => "something"
abort()
```

The result page only displays "exit"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `return` from your action. Don't `abort()`.

As an aside, there are far, far better ways of debugging Rails programs. Look into [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) or just `logger.info`.

Ideally, if you've hit some error state, you should be raising an appropriate exception, and *leaving that in your codebase*. You can then temporarily add `binding.pry` or logging statements for debugging, which should come out of your codebase when you've got that area working correctly. It is virtually *never* correct to simply dump a textual error string to the browser and "exit" with a successful response code.

Comment: this is breaking MVC pattern though isn't it?

Comment: Note that PHP and Rails have different models. In PHP, each page is essentially run as its own instance of the program, so exiting the entire program when you're done is fine. In Rails, though, there's one instance of the program that receives requests and outputs responses. Aborting during a request aborts the entire *server*.

Comment: @sircapsalot: in what way? Returning text from a controller action is a reasonable MVC thing to do, but the logging techniques that meager recommends are preferred for non-MVC reasons.

Comment: is it?  i'm very new to understanding MVC, and i would think anything rendered to the user should be handled in the view.

Comment: @sircapsalot The controller is responsible for responding to the user, it just happens to pick a view to render a model into a specific type of output more often than not.

Comment: fair enough :)  i have seen things like `render 'new'` to render the `new.html.erb` before, so i guess it makes sense to render something else like text rather than having an entirely new file

Comment: Not only that, but you'll often find things like `render json: @myModel.as_json` or the like. It's pretty common for there to be new view involved in a request at all.